# More than you could have ever imagined

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

which phrase really **exists**?

(Situation between two persons)

> Question: how far does a mother's love can be?
>
> Answer: **more than you can imagine**
>
> or
>
> **more than you could have ever imagined**

Do these two exist or just one?

Comment: Pearl tilted the box so Cinder could see. Inside was the finest pair of gloves she could have imagined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both your bold expressions are grammatically correct. Their meanings are similar, but not the same (the difference is the tense)

The part which is poor English is the question "how far does a mother's love can be?" The auxiliary "does" is not used with the modal "can". And you probably want to use a more specific verb than "be".  Perhaps "How far can a mother's love stretch?"